# How do i do mysql query to find a RandomID, with the same date and EstID in the same result?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE log_tbl
(ID int, RandomID varchar(200), EstID int, Date date, Time time);

INSERT INTO `log_tbl` (`ID`, `RandomID`, `EstID`, `Date`, `Time`) VALUES
    (1,"TYS70POO7KW","3","2021-06-15","20:43:07"),
    (2,"KJD86DVZ6NL","1","2021-06-15"," 18:59:42"),
    (3,"ZOW10DVZ3AI","1","2022-06-12","12:17:26"),
    (4,"DZB06PSA6YS","1","2021-06-17","14:54:27"),
    (5,"PZA42IST5YD","3","2021-06-12","12:36:35"),
    (6,"JWM21TQS8LE","3","2021-06-12","05:53:44"),
    (7,"LIN78JFF5WG","2","2021-06-16","04:54:25"),
    (8,"OGY65YUH7IF","2","2021-06-12","18:57:13"),
    (9,"IZX04GUF5TJ","3","2021-06-12","15:35:27"),
    (10,"YEL10NDQ4OV","2","2021-06-15","10:43:00"),
    (11,"TYS70POO7KW","2","2021-06-17","20:43:07"),
    (12,"KJD86DVZ6NL","2","2021-06-17","18:59:42"),
    (13,"ZOW10DVZ3AI","3","2022-06-17","12:17:26"),
    (14,"DZB06PSA6YS","2","2021-06-16","14:54:27"),
    (15,"PZA42IST5YD","1","2021-06-12","12:36:35"),
    (16,"JWM21TQS8LE","2","2021-06-12","05:53:44"),
    (17,"LIN78JFF5WG","3","2021-06-13","04:54:25"),
    (18,"OGY65YUH7IF","3","2021-06-13","18:57:13"),
    (19,"IZX04GUF5TJ","1","2021-06-12","15:35:27"),
    (20,"YEL10NDQ4OV","1","2021-06-12","10:43:00"),
    (21,"TYS70POO7KW","1","2021-06-17","20:43:07"),
    (22,"KJD86DVZ6NL","2","2021-06-17","18:59:42"),
    (23,"ZOW10DVZ3AI","3","2022-06-17","12:17:26"),
    (24,"DZB06PSA6YS","2","2021-06-17","14:54:27"),
    (25,"PZA42IST5YD","2","2021-06-12","12:36:35"),
    (26,"JWM21TQS8LE","2","2021-06-12","05:53:44"),
    (27,"LIN78JFF5WG","3","2021-06-14","04:54:25"),
    (28,"OGY65YUH7IF","1","2021-06-14","18:57:13"),
    (29,"IZX04GUF5TJ","1","2021-06-14","15:35:27"),
    (30,"YEL10NDQ4OV","3","2021-06-16","10:43:00");
```

From the table above, I want to search a specific user(`RandomID`) and show all the other users that had the same `EstID` on the same Date.
I also need to narrow down result, only showing 2 hours before and after `RandomID` was logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `in` with tuples:

```
select l.*
from log_tbl l
where (l.est_id, l.date) in (select l2.est_id, l2.date
                             from log_tbl l2
                             where l2.randomid = ?
                            );
```

Comment: That `?` you have to replace with a `RandomID` that you need to lookup. And what version of MariaDB you're using?

Comment: 10.4.19, but its ok now. i messed up the syntax.

but i need help again, to narrow down the result into 2 hours before and after, but still the same date,

Comment: You have to post a new question @SplitStream. This question is already considered as solved. With a new question, you'll get more chance of getting attention.